# Using useEffect and useContext while fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to learn how to use React's Context API as well as Hooks, and trying to work on a project where I'm using fetch().

When using both, I get the request, but I can't get the data I set, except for `loading`.

```
import React,{useState, createContext} from 'react';

export const ProductsContext = createContext();

export const ProductsProvider = props => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState({ categories: {} });
    const [products, setProducts] = useState({ products: {} });
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const [categoriesResult, productsResult] = await Promise.all([fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/categories'), fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/products')]);
            setCategories(categoriesResult);
            setProducts(productsResult);
            setLoading(false);
          })();
        }, []);
    return (
    <ProductsContext.Provider value={ { products, categories, loading } }>
        {props.children}
    </ProductsContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Here I'm creating a context where I'd like to pass products (and categories) through the Provider.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ProductsContext } from './ProductsContext';


const Products = () => {
    const {products, categories, loading} = useContext(ProductsContext);
    return (
        <div className="products">
            { console.log(products, categories, loading) }
        </div>
    ); 
};
```

Page

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Banner from './Banner';
import ProductsContainer from './Products/ProductsContainer';
import {ProductsProvider} from './Products/ProductsContext';
const Page = () => (

    <>
      <Header/>
      <Banner/>
      <ProductsProvider>
        <ProductsContainer/>
      </ProductsProvider>
    </>

);

export default Page;
```

This is the results I get via console.log:

```
{products: {…}} Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/categories", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} true
Products.js:9 Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/products", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/categories", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} true
Products.js:9 Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/products", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/categories", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} false
Products.js:9 Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/products", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/categories", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} false
Products.js:9 Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/products", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/categories", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} false
Products.js:9 Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/products", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/categories", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} false
```

As you can see, there is no data, but loading changes.

What am I doing wrong? How can I pass products via Context API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At casual reading, the React.useContext() looks serviceable. The issue I see is that the React state variables, `categories` and `product` are being set to the Response from `fetch()` and according to [MDN's fetch() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), fetch returns a value that resolves from a Promise to a Response, which is not quite what you want.

But this is close! You should do something like

```
  setCategories(categoriesResult.json());
  setProducts(productsResult.json());
```

or figure out another way to massage the `Response.Body` into a form that you can manipulate. [Check out the API reference for Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

---

To resolve the promise, you call `promise.then(...)` where `promise` is the **Promise** object returned from `fetch()`.

To that end, I would suggest separating the two fetches in order to make resolving the promises simple and possibly make other parts of your interface respond sooner (i.e. if one fetch comes in before the other, you could render those results even if you don't have the other. Even if you want to wait until both parts are complete, you could make your rendering contingent on `loading`'s state.)

```
export const ProductsProvider = props => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const [categories, setCategories] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/categories')
      .then((response) => {
         setCategories(response.json());
      }
    setLoading(/* false only if categories AND product are not {} */);
  }, []);

  // Repeat the above, except for products

  return (
    <ProductsContext.Provider value={ { products, categories, loading } }>
      {props.children}
    </ProductsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This sort of works, however when console.log the response, `{ console.log(products, categories, loading) }` I get the data but it's in `[[PromiseValue]]`. How would I access the data from this?

Comment: Yeah, you've wrapped two Promises into another Promise, so you'd need to resolve the outer Promise as well as the inner ones, and frankly it's complicating things unnecessarily. See updated answer for a simple solution.